# Breakng the hash

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, hashcode

I have to break 4 hash codes and find their number . but my code is not working

these are the hash codes (in a csv file) :

```
javad :f478525457dcd5ec6223e52bd3df32d1edb600275e18d6435cdeb3ef2294e8de
milad : 297219e7de424bb52c040e7a2cbbd9024f7af18e283894fe59ca6abc0313c3c4
tahmine : 6621ead3c9ec19dfbd65ca799cc387320c1f22ac0c6b3beaae9de7ef190668c4
niloofar : 26d72e99775e03d2501416c6f402c265e628b7d02eee17a7671563c32e0cd9a3
```

my code :

```
import hashlib
import itertools as it
import csv
from typing import Dict
number=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
code = hashlib.sha256()
passwords = list(it.permutations(number, 4))

with open('passwords.csv', newline='') as theFile:
    reader = csv.reader(theFile)
    

passdic = dict()
# hpass is hash password
for hpass in passwords :
    
    encoded_hpass = ''.join(map(str, hpass)).encode('ascii')
    
    code = hashlib.sha256()
    code.update(encoded_hpass)

    passdic[encoded_hpass] = code.digest()
    
    for row in theFile :
        for key, value in row.items():
            passdic[key].append(value)
```

and my result is :

```
'C:\Users\Parsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\Users\Parsa\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher' '3262' '--' 'c:\Users\Parsa\Desktop\project\hash breaker.py'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Parsa\Desktop\project\hash breaker.py", line 24, in <module>
    for row in theFile :
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to read from a closed file, which is impossible.

I don't know what your code is supposed to do, but here are the unlogical parts:

This opens the file to parse it as CSV

```
with open('passwords.csv', newline='') as theFile:
    reader = csv.reader(theFile)
```

Then later on you run:

```
    for row in theFile :
        for key, value in row.items():
```

But now, you're outside of the `with` block and the file is closed.

I guess you should use `reader` in place of `theFile`. If you really intend to loop over the raw line of the file, you need to wrap the loop again in a `with open` statement.